# Loading vaex dataframe to dash datatable

Tags: python, pandas, flask, plotly-dash, vaex

I am trying to load a dataframe(vaex) to dash datatable and getting following error.

**Invalid argument `data` passed into DataTable with ID "table".
Expected an array.
Was supplied type `object`.**

Tried the following, is it possible to load vaex dataframe to dash datatable like pandas dataframe.

```
import vaex
import dash
# import dash_table
from dash import dash_table
import pandas as pd

df = vaex.open('./customer_list_100.csv.hdf5')
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    data=df.to_dict(),
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Try using `df.to_dict('records')`.

Comment: @ChuckTucker, already tried that but getting ```name 'records' is not defined```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the [vaex docs](https://vaex.io/docs/api.html?highlight=to_records#vaex.dataframe.DataFrame.to_records) and testing, it looks like you need to use the code below to get the proper data orientation:

```py
data = df.to_records()
```

vaex doesn't give you the option to specify an `orient` arg like pandas, instead, you just use `to_records()`.